# Swift how to change background color of a Section Header in a List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to change the background color of this List's Section Header, the below only colors the background of the Text View itself.  I also don't want to globally change `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor` because this then affects other views?

```
 List {
                            Section(header: Text("Summary")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                        .background(Color.red).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            ) {
                                Text("\(filterThisMonthsWorkouts(workouts: athlyticDataStore.workouts).count) workouts")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
                                Text("\(TimeFormatters().formatTimeAsDoubleToHoursAndMinutesOnly(duration: filterThisMonthsWorkouts(workouts: athlyticDataStore.workouts).map { $0.duration }.reduce(0, +)))")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
                                Text("\(Int(filterThisMonthsWorkouts(workouts: athlyticDataStore.workouts).map { $0.totalEnergyBurned }.reduce(0, +))) calories burned")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(height: sizeCategory > ContentSizeCategory.large ? 200 : 165)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                        .padding([.horizontal, .top])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
 Text(...)   
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Edit:
Above works for Form but with List it will be some edge to both leading and trailing sides, the area aligned with content.

Put this to the last can fill the full header width:

```
            Section(header: Text("hi")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: -10, leading: -10, bottom: -10, trailing: -10)
```

Comment: Thanks, that expands to fill up most of the width of the List (also adding `maxHeight: .infinity`) but it does not fill the entire area that is taken up by the header unfortunately.

Comment: It fills the full header with now but not the height on the top or bottom

Comment: this breaks when you add a Picker inside the section